# Clarification on subscription behavior in CPQ when multiple revisions occur to a subscription, does it chain or do both point to the original sub?

Tags: cpq, contracts, entitysubscription

If I have a contract in SF CPQ with subscription x1 at quantity 100, I amend it to be quantity 200. This creates subscription x2 which has a revised subscription pointer to x1. I then amend it again to add another 100 quant, for a total of 300 quant. This creates another subscription x3, however the revised subscription pointer, should it now point to x1 or x2? Is it revising the original subscription or the revised subscription?

The context here is that a contract was consolidated and we are trying to manually construct the correct subscription behavior for past amendments that, ideally, should have all been on the same contract in the first place but are not. As far as business restrictions go a new contract cannot be created, we cannot recreate the sales process (redo oppty thru order), or anything like that.

In summation, if a subscription is revised twice does it form a chain of revised subscriptions or do both amendments/revisions point to the same original subscription?

EDIT: found answer

Comment: Ran test in sandbox, both point to original.

Answer (score 0):

Ran test in sandbox, both point to original.